# Modules from @react-native-community

Tags: react-native

It took me quite a few days to figure out I need to install the latest react-native cli from `@react-native-community/cli` but not from `react-native-cli` as I used to do.

Do:

```
yarn add @react-native-community/cli
```

but not:

```
yarn add react-native-cli
```

There are quite many modules now under `@react-native-community`, my question is that when I should install from `@react-native-community/module_name` and when just `react-native-modulename`.

Comment: It depends. `@react-native-community` is an organization in npm packages. If the package publish under an organization, it will be installed as `@<organization>/<package>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lots of libraries used to be a part of `react-native` library, but recently they decided to move them out. So now modules like `react-native-camera` can be installed via `npm install react-native-camera` and then imported from `react-native-camera` package.

It's easy to understand when to install a package from npm and when just import from `react-native`. If your import tells you that there is no such module in core lib, just go to npm and check it there.

Comment: Both modules exist and that's why it may be confusing.

Comment: Actually if we're talking exactly about  react-native-cli you don't need it in actual version of react-native. Go through the tutorial of facebook (and pay attention at this line: `If you previously installed a global react-native-cli package, please remove it as it may cause unexpected issues.`): https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started